# C# Entity Framework OrderBy Children's Children's with a where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-order-by

I have a pretty complicated linq statement that gets a list of people (using Entity Framework) and I want to add an `OrderBy` clause to the end, depending on which column the user has clicked on for sorting. I DON'T want to get all the people and then sort as there are potentially alot of people and we also do paging, so getting the data and then sorting/paging is not an option. It must therefore be done using LINQ to EF.

I have managed to get the search criteria that filters based on the status of the user's current vaccination status, but I am unable to "convert" that to an `OrderBy` statement

The data I am getting relates to COVID vaccinations and whether the person's vaccination status is Full, Partial, Not Disclosed or None.

The Entity Framework LINQ statement with the `Where` clause looks like this and It is an `IQueryable<Person>`, not a `List<Person>`:

```
people.Where(p => p.Encounters.Where(e =>
          e.EncounterItems.Any(ei => ei.PersonAssessments.Any(pa =>
          pa.Assessment.Questions.Any(q => q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))))
          .OrderByDescending(e => e.servicedt ?? e.planneddt).FirstOrDefault()
          .EncounterItems.Where(ei =>
          ei.PersonAssessments.Any(pa => pa.Answers.Any(a => a.adate.HasValue && DbFunctions.AddMonths(a.adate, procedureCycleDays) < DateTime.Today &&
          (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
          && (!pa.Answers.Any(aa => aa.adate.HasValue && aa.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
          ))))).FirstOrDefault()
          != null)
```

From the above it will filter the people where their vaccination status is "Overdue". i.e they have done either Partial or Full Vaccination but the cycle for this vaccination has been exceeded. There are 2 questions with questioncode's "qIDateP" (partial) and "qIDateF" (full).

I know the below `OrderBy` is completly wrong, but I want to do something like this so that all the people with overdue vaccination status's are at the top. I will then add several other `OrderBy` clauses such as "Current" using the same clause, just chainging the date expression e.g. `DbFunctions.AddMonths(a.adate, procedureCycleDays) >= DateTime.Today`

```
people.OrderBy(p => p.Encounters.Where(e =>
       e.EncounterItems.Any(ei => ei.PersonAssessments.Any(pa =>
       pa.Assessment.Questions.Any(q => q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))))
       .OrderByDescending(e => e.servicedt ?? e.planneddt).FirstOrDefault()
       .EncounterItems.Where(ei =>
       ei.PersonAssessments.Any(pa => pa.Answers.Any(a => a.adate.HasValue && DbFunctions.AddMonths(a.adate, procedureCycleDays) < DateTime.Today &&
       (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
       && (!pa.Answers.Any(aa => aa.adate.HasValue && aa.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
       ))))).FirstOrDefault()
       != null)
```

The Relationships for the EF Models is as follows:

```
Person => Encounter => EncounterItem => PersonAssessment => Answer
```

A person can answer multiple Assessments over their life and can change their mind as to whether they want to disclose their vaccination status or not.

NOTE: We are using the latest Entity Framework 6.4.4

I hope someone can help me with the OrderBy clause as Im at a complete loss as to how to achieve this.

***------UPDATE 1-------***

I have used this so far.

```
people.OrderBy(p => p.Encounters.Where(
              e => e.EncounterItems.Any(
                ei => ei.PersonAssessments.Any(
                  pa => pa.Assessment.Questions.Any(
                    q => q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                      || q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))))).OrderByDescending(e => e.servicedt ?? e.planneddt).FirstOrDefault() // you have 1 Encounters item
                .EncounterItems.DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault(
                  ei => ei.PersonAssessments.Any(
                    pa => pa.Answers.Any(
                      a => a.adate.HasValue
                      && DbFunctions.AddMonths(a.adate, procedureCycleDays) < DateTime.Today
                      && (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                        || (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                          && (!pa.Answers.Any(aa => aa.adate.HasValue && aa.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))))))).Encounter.planneddt)
```

The issue is that all the "Overdue" records are at the bottom, not at the top. If I use `OrderByDescending` it seems correct. How can I now put all those records at the top with `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByDescending`.

***------ UPDATE 2 Final Solution ------***

After a couple of changes based on [Margus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97754/margus) answer below I have the final updated `OrderBy`. I had to `OrderBydescending` for some reason in order to get the records that I wanted at the top.

```
people.OrderByDescending(p => p.Encounters.Where(
    e => e.EncounterItems.Any(
    ei => ei.PersonAssessments.Any(
    pa => pa.Assessment.Questions.Any(
    q => q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    || q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))))).OrderByDescending(e => e.servicedt ?? e.planneddt).FirstOrDefault() // you have 1 Encounters item.EncounterItems.DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault(
    ei => ei.PersonAssessments.Any(
    pa => pa.Answers.Any(
    a => a.adate.HasValue
    && DbFunctions.AddMonths(a.adate, procedureCycleDays) < DateTime.Today
    && (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    || (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    && (!pa.Answers.Any(aa => aa.adate.HasValue && aa.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))))))).Encounter.planneddt)
```

Now Im concerned about the performance lol... But that will be another stackoverflow search :)

Answer (score 1):

Well as far as I can tell you want to use orderBy and then simply fetch the first element, while you could simply fetch the first element with the same predicate dropping O(nlogn) complexity

```cs
var result = people.Where(
    p => p.Encounters.Where(
        e => e.EncounterItems.Any(
            ei => ei.PersonAssessments.Any(
                pa => pa.Assessment.Questions.Any(
                    q => q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
                      || q.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))))
      .FirstOrDefault(e => e.servicedt ?? e.planneddt) // you have 1 Encounters item
      .EncounterItems.FirstOrDefault(
        ei => ei.PersonAssessments.Any(
            pa => pa.Answers.Any(
                a => a.adate.HasValue 
                    && DbFunctions.AddMonths(a.adate, procedureCycleDays) < DateTime.Today 
                      && (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
                        || (a.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                          && (!pa.Answers.Any(aa => aa.adate.HasValue && aa.Question.questioncode.Equals("qIDateF", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))))))));
```

Comment: Bravo! Seeing `)))))))));` to close a nest would terrify me 

Comment: Surely you can't be serious... Is it that simple?? Ill try it tomorrow at work and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: HHmmm... I am getting this error: System.ArgumentException: 'DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
Parameter name: key'

Any Ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the help Margus... I have edited my question with my final updated OrderBy